# What sense does it make to flush a StringWriter in Java?

Tags: java

StringWriter has a [flush](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/StringWriter.html#flush%28%29) function. What does it mean to flush a string buffer?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It must have an implementation of `flush()` because in its superclass `Writer` that's an abstract method, and `StringWriter` is not an abstract class. However, if you look at the source code of `StringWriter.flush()`, which you can find in the file `src.zip` in your JDK installation directory, you'll see:

```
/**
 * Flush the stream.
 */
public void flush() {
}
```

In other words, it does nothing. (There are ofcourse other subclasses of `Writer` where `flush()` does do something useful).

The person who implemented this method could have documented that it doesn't do anything, but they didn't.

Comment: @mishadoff For that, see the answers by others on your question. Also the API documentation of `java.io.Writer.flush()` explains what this method is for.

Comment: I mean exact this implementation of `flush` :)

Comment: @mishadoff As you see, it does nothing. What's to not understand about that?

Answer (score 2):

In general a flush forces a buffer to write its content to the destination, for example writing the bytes to the file on the harddisk.

Comment: StringWriter writes to memory and not to a hard disk.

Comment: yeah, I just edited to make it more general. thanks for advice.

Comment: You didn't make it into an answer to OP's question, though. We can safely assume this is what OP knows and is in fact the reason why he asked the question.