# Printing Stack Trace to textarea

Tags: java, exception

I am printing Stack Trace to `JTextArea` using the below code :

```
        try
        {
            throw new IOException();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace(pw);
            ta1.append(sw.toString());
        }
        pw.flush();
        sw.flush();
        try
        {
            throw new SQLException();
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace(pw);
            ta1.append(sw.toString());
        }
```

It prints out 2 `IOException` traces and 1 `SQLExeption` trace.
Why is not stringwriter flushed out ?

I want 1 `IOException` trace and 1 `SQLExeption` trace.

Please suggest proper way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The `flush` method of `StringWriter` does nothing !
The `flush` method is just there to be compatible with `java.io.Writer`.

`StringWriter` source :

```
/**
 * Flush the stream.
 */
public void flush() {
}
```

And `PrintWriter` call the `StringWriter` `flush` method ...

`PrintWriter`  source :

```
/**
 * Flushes the stream.
 * @see #checkError()
 */
public void flush() {
    try {
        synchronized (lock) {
            ensureOpen();
            out.flush();
        }
    }
    catch (IOException x) {
        trouble = true;
    }
}
```

So if you want to clear `pw` and `sw` you should not use `flush` method. You need to create a new one.

see :

[What sense does it make to flush a StringWriter in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12508450/1811730)

[How do you "empty" a StringWriter in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3738095/1811730)

Comment: what if program has a lot to print , so will I be creating new writers every time for just an append? Is there any other class than `StringWriter` which implements flush to clear its underlying buffer?

Comment: It is difficult to help without the rest of code... Perhaps you can find a subclass of StringWriter with a flush method that works. Or rewrite your code without StringWriter ... StringBuilder / StringBuffer  is specifically designed for assembling string (StringWriter use StringBuffer...) but i don't know if it is possible in your code.